# xdmp.tidy(html) removes useful Article tags

Tags: html, xhtml, marklogic, htmltidy, sjs

I'm using Marklogic 8. While using [xdmp.tidy()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.tidy) to clean and convert HTML to XHTML, it deletes useful "article" tags.

Any fix or options to ignore few tags? Do we have other alternative conversion technique?

Things Already checked:

- http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html
- https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp/conversion
- https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.tidy

Comment: Found an option <new-inline-tags>article section</new-inline-tags>
  <new-blocklevel-tags>article section</new-blocklevel-tags>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can add new HTMl5 tags using tidy options.

```
var options = {"newBlocklevelTags":"article section"};
var cleanHtml=xdmp.tidy(html, options);
```

Comment: Looks like you were able to answer your own question. Nice! Don't forget to accept your answer, to let others know that the problem has been solved and that this will work for them.